# Angular delete entity Error 405 HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException

Tags: html, spring, angular, typescript, request

I've coded an application which makes CRUD operations over a list of entities.
But e.g. for the case of deleting an entity, the resulting dialog doesn't appear.

First, I've a HttpService that is the base for the CRUD operations:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    static API_END_POINT = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v0';

    private params: URLSearchParams;

    private headers: Headers;

    private responseType: ResponseContentType;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.params = new URLSearchParams();
        this.headers = new Headers();
    }

delete(endpoint: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete(HttpService.API_END_POINT + endpoint, this.createOptions()).map(
            response => this.extractData(response)).catch(
                error => {
                    return this.handleError(error);
                });
    }

}
```

For the entity, I use an Injectable service (CustomerService):

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {
    static END_POINT = '/customers';

    constructor(private httpService: HttpService, public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    }

   deleteObservable(customer: Customer): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.httpService.delete(CustomerService.END_POINT).map(
            data => {
                this.successful();
                return data;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Then there's the menu component when, for every entity (Customer), I can choose to delete it:

The menu component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
    static URL = 'customers';

    displayedColumns = [ 'id', 'name', 'address', 'date', 'actions'];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Customer>;
    customers = this.dataSource;

    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private customerService: CustomerService) {
    }

...

delete(customer: Customer) {
        this.customerService.readObservable(customer.id).subscribe(
              data => {
                const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CustomerDeleteDialogComponent);
                dialogRef.componentInstance.customer = data;
                dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
                    result => this.synchronize()
                );
           }
        );
    }
}
```

And the menu html template:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.id}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.name}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <button mat-icon-button color="accent" (click)="delete(customer)">
            <mat-icon aria-label="Delete">delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
</mat-card>
```

The dialog component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-customer-delete-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'customer-delete-dialog.component.html',
    styles: [`.mat-dialog-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }`]
})
export class CustomerDeleteDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    customer: Customer;

    constructor(private customerService: CustomerService,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CustomerDeleteDialogComponent>) { }

    delete(): void {
        this.customerService.deleteObservable(this.customer).subscribe(
            data => this.dialogRef.close()
        );
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (!this.customer) {}
        this.customer = { id: undefined, name: '', address: '', date: undefined };
        }
}
```

And the dialog html template:

```
<mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-icon color="warn">warning</mat-icon> <h3>Confirm: Delete Customer. Are you sure?</h3>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close cdkFocusInitial color="primary">Cancel</button>
    <button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="true"  (click)="delete()">Ok. Delete</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

If I choose to delete a Customer and confirm that through the previous dialog, I receive an exception:

"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException, message:Request method 'DELETE' not supported, path:/api/v0/customers"

My question is **where is the error**, in **Spring or Angular**? Because the resources tests in angular where correct and I can use the same API to create customers. Any help would be great!

If it helps, here's the Spring code for:

the resource...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(CustomerResource.CUSTOMERS)
public class CustomerResource {

    public static final String CUSTOMERS = "/customers";

    public static final String ID = "/{id}";

    private CustomerController customerController;

    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerController(CustomerController customerController) {
        this.customerController = customerController;
    }

@RequestMapping(value = ID, method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable String id) {
        customerController.deleteCustomer(id);
    }

}
```

... and the controller

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

public void deleteCustomer(String id) {
        if (customerDao.exists(id)) {
            customerDao.delete(id);
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit**:

This is the delete request test, which goes correctly:

```
@Test
    public void deleteCustomer() {
        this.deleteCustomer("222");
    }

    private void deleteCustomer(String id) {
        new RestBuilder<Object>(port).path(contextPath).path(CustomerResource.CUSTOMERS).path(CustomerResource.ID).delete().build();
    }

 @Test
    public void deleteCustomer() {
        this.deleteCustomer("222");
    }

    private void deleteCustomer(String id) {
        new RestBuilder<Object>(port).path(contextPath).path(CustomerResource.CUSTOMERS).path(CustomerResource.ID).delete().build();
    }
```

Furthermore, the POST method (to create new Customers) works, and I think it's similar:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(CustomerResource.CUSTOMERS)
public class CustomerResource {

    public static final String CUSTOMERS = "/customers";

    public static final String ID = "/{id}";

    private CustomerController customerController;

...

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDto customerDto) {
        return customerController.createCustomer(customerDto);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception, `"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException, message:Request method 'DELETE' not supported, path:/api/v0/customers"` the problem is in spring, you haven't correctly define the ressource url.
You can check first if the path is well written and then use postman to debug your spring application before connecting to frontend.

Comment: Ok, but why it's correct the test when I have launched it? (see edit)

Comment: I've test with Postman, first creating a Customer and then deleting the same customer. And all it's OK. But since the Angular app doesn't refresh automatically the list with the customers after the deletion with Postman (but does after creating a new Customer with my app) , I see that the error is in Angular.